# How can I group an ordered array of ints using Linq

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have an ordered array of numbers {1,2,3,4,5,9,10,11,13}.
Need to group them like this: {1,2,3,4,5}, {9,10,11}, {13}.
I solve this problem using for-loop:

```
// An ordered array
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13};
        List<List<int>> listOfGroupNum = new List<List<int>>();
        List<int> listofNumbers = new List<int>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
        {
            // Take two numbers
            // If a difference betwen them -1 adding to a group
            if (((i + 1) < numbers.Length) && (numbers[i] - numbers[i + 1] == -1))
            {
                listofNumbers.Add(numbers[i]);
                continue;
            }
            listofNumbers.Add(numbers[i]);
            listOfGroupNum.Add(listofNumbers);
            listofNumbers = new List<int>();
        }
```

Is there a way to solve this problem using Linq?

**Update:**
I found a LINQ expression, answeres on my question:

```
        int[] numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 9, 10, 11, 13};
        var groups =
            numbers.Select((x, i) => new {Difference = i - x, Value = x})
                .GroupBy(x => x.Difference)
                .Select(x => x.Select(y => y.Value).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: And why do you want some LINQ? I bet this will become hard to read.Your solution is pretty straightforward, why overcomplicate it with LINQ? It won´t get better, or faster, just harder to read.

Comment: I would rather use `Range` method. `IEnumerable<int> squares = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).Select(x => x * x)`;

Comment: LINQ generally executes an operation on each individual element of a collection. That's not what you're trying to do here, you're evaluating the relation **between** elements. I'd avoid LINQ for this one.

Comment: @andrey.shedko: I fail to see how creating a list of squares is relevant here.

Comment: I think this solution is not bad, but my "mind-compiler" said: "This solution is good, but not perfect -  make it perfect ." Therefore I think LINQ will be better